# jQuery-PHP relation problem or how to dynamically include php content

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, include

I'm making a web application that uses gadgets, and one of them is horoscope. I detect if the user added their birth date to their profile information, and if not I display three dropdown menus (`<select>`) and a button for submitting. When the user fill in the "form" and click the button, with ajax I write these parameters into MySQL, and then I call:
`$("#the_id").load("gadgets/horoscope.php");`  in my .js file
and in that div it displays an error every time. Sometimes "you didn't include rss class" (i read the horoscope with rss), sometimes "I can't connect to mysql" (this is to check if there is a record, not for writing). So my question is how to avoid all these errors, beacause when I include that gadget files with php, for the first time, there's no problem.
Hope you understood me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You avoid the errors by fixing the errors in the PHP script you're calling. Without code that is as much help as can be given.

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot without seeing your code.  It could be a scope thing, paths, etc..

Answer (score 0):

This is my php code (the gadget):
`

```
                $rss = new RSSReader("http://magicaura.com/rss");

                $astro = $rss->getNumberOfNews();
                //$astro = $rss->getItemDescription("");
                //$astro = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $astro);
                //$astro = nl2br($astro);

                $months = array('изберете', 'януари', 'февруари', 'март', 'април', 'май', 'юни', 'юли', 'август', 'септември', 'октомври', 'ноември', 'декември');


                $oven       = createDateRange(date("Y")."-03-21", date("Y")."-04-20");
                $telec      = createDateRange(date("Y")."-04-21", date("Y")."-05-20");
                $bliznaci   = createDateRange(date("Y")."-05-21", date("Y")."-06-21");
                $rak        = createDateRange(date("Y")."-06-22", date("Y")."-07-22");
                $lav        = createDateRange(date("Y")."-07-23", date("Y")."-08-22");
                $deva       = createDateRange(date("Y")."-08-23", date("Y")."-09-22");
                $vezni      = createDateRange(date("Y")."-09-23", date("Y")."-10-22");
                $scorpion   = createDateRange(date("Y")."-10-23", date("Y")."-11-22");
                $strelec    = createDateRange(date("Y")."-11-23", date("Y")."-12-21");
                $kozirog    = createDateRange(date("Y")."-12-22", date("Y")."-20-01");
                $vodolei    = createDateRange(date("Y")."-01-21", date("Y")."-02-19");
                $ribi       = createDateRange(date("Y")."-02-20", date("Y")."-03-20");

                $zodiacFormat = date("Y")."-".$userVars['user_birth_month']."-".$userVars['user_birth_day'];



                if(in_array($zodiacFormat, $oven))      { $usersSign="овен"; $zodiacImage = "aries"; }
                if(in_array($zodiacFormat, $telec))     { $usersSign="телец"; $zodiacImage = "taurus"; }
                if(in_array($zodiacFormat, $bliznaci))  { $usersSign="близнаци"; $zodiacImage = "gamini"; }
                if(in_array($zodiacFormat, $rak))       { $usersSign="рак"; $zodiacImage = "cancer"; }
                if(in_array($zodiacFormat, $lav))       { $usersSign="лъв"; $zodiacImage = "leo"; }
                if(in_array($zodiacFormat, $deva))      { $usersSign="дева"; $zodiacImage = "virgo"; }
                if(in_array($zodiacFormat, $vezni))     { $usersSign="везни"; $zodiacImage = "libra"; }
                if(in_array($zodiacFormat, $scorpion))  { $usersSign="скорпион"; $zodiacImage = "scorpio"; }
                if(in_array($zodiacFormat, $strelec))   { $usersSign="стрелец"; $zodiacImage = "sagittarius"; }
                if(in_array($zodiacFormat, $kozirog))   { $usersSign="козирог"; $zodiacImage = "capricorn"; }
                if(in_array($zodiacFormat, $vodolei))   { $usersSign="водолей"; $zodiacImage = "aquarius"; }
                if(in_array($zodiacFormat, $ribi))      { $usersSign="риби"; $zodiacImage = "pisces"; }

                $yearList="";
                $y=0;
                for($y=1900;$y<=date("Y");$y++)
                {
                    $yearList .= '<option value="'.$y.'">'.$y.'</option>';
                }

                $z=0;
                for($z=0;$z<=count($countArray);$z++) {
                    $zodiq =iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $rss->getItemTitle("", $z));

                    if(eregi($usersSign, $zodiq)) {
                        echo '<tr><td align="left">&lt;</td><td align="center"><img src="design/thm/'.$_SESSION['thm'].'/img/'.$zodiacImage.'.png" width="24" height="24" border="0" align="absmiddle" />&nbsp;<b>'.$zodiq.'</b></td><td align="right">&gt;</td></tr>';
                        echo '<tr><td height="10"></td></tr>';
                        echo '<tr><td align="center" colspan="3"><p align="justify">'.iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $rss->getItemDescription("", $z)).'</p></td></tr>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<tr><td align="right">Месец:&nbsp;</td>';
                        echo '<td align="left"><select name="birth_month" id="birth_month" class="select">';
                            echo monthList($months);
                        echo '</select></td></tr>';

                        echo '<tr><td height="3"></td></tr>';

                        echo '<tr><td align="right">Ден:&nbsp;</td>';
                        echo '<td align="left"><select name="birth_day" id="birth_day" disabled="disabled" class="select">';
                            echo '<option value="0">изберете месец</option>';
                        echo '</select></td></tr>';

                        echo '<tr><td height="3"></td></tr>';

                        echo '<tr><td align="right">Година:&nbsp;</td>';
                        echo '<td align="left"><select name="birth_year" id="birth_year" class="select">';
                            echo ''.$yearList.'';
                        echo '</select></td></tr>';
                        echo '<tr><td height="10"></td></tr>';
                        echo '<tr><td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Въведи" class="button" disabled="disabled" id="astro_btn" /></td></tr>';
                        echo '<tr><td height="10"></td></tr>';
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </table>
        </td>
    </td>
</tr>
```

`
The whole thing is in div#horoscope_id

Here is my js function:
`
$("#astro_btn").click(function(){
        var birthDay    = $("#birth_day").val();
        var birthMonth  = $("#birth_month").val();
        var birthYear   = $("#birth_year").val();

```
    callAjax("the url to file writing in db", "userBirthDay="+birthDay+"&userBirthMonth="+birthMonth+"&userBirthYear="+birthYear);
    $("#horoscope_id").empty();
    $("#horoscope_id").load("gadgets/horoscope/index.php");
});
```

`